# python HTML print a list

Tags: python, html, css

here is part of my script. i have a list called content in this code that contains a bunch of ascii in it. my question is how do you print out all those ascii in the rows and columns. all im getting in the url is a word content rather than whats in that list. everything else works, so i just need to know how to display whats in that list

```
print (''' <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lab 5.1.cgi</title>
        <style type="text/css">
             body {background-color:white;font-style:none;font-weight:normal; font-family:Gill Sans, Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:30px;color:#c00; text-shadow:0 0 2px black,0px 0px 8px white; background:url(data:image/gif;base64,%s);text-align:center} h1 {font-size:72px;font-weight:bold} h2 {font-weight:normal} div {font-family:Arial;font-size:30px;color:black; text-shadow:none;background-color:white;width:440px;margin:0 auto} .source {width:960px}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                <div class="globalWrapper">
                    <div>
                        <strong>lab5.1.cgi</strong>
                        <h1 class="title">Arial Unicode MS</h1>
                        <h2 class="small">Printable Characters: 32&ndash;126, 128 &ndash; 4000</h2>
                        %s
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>''' % (external_link, content))
```

this is basically whats in the list

```
for i in range(33,127):
    content.append('<div class="unicode-char">')
    char = cgi.escape(chr(i)).encode("ascii", "xmlcharrefreplace")
    content.append(char.decode())
    content.append('<div class="clearfix"></div><sub style="font-size: 12px">{sub_number}</sub>'.format(sub_number = i))
    content.append('</div>')
```

UPDATE: found a way to print the list but it just prints in one long row. what am i doing wrong. thought i set it to b 12 columns

Comment: Doing this manually will be a pain. Google 'BeautifulSoup' and let it do the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `content` is a Python list, then you can convert that to HTML with

```
''.join(content)
```

If you want every element in the list on a different line, use:

```
'\n'.join(content)
```

If you see everything in a single line in the browser, show us the CSS for `unicode-char`